# How to load the selected option JSON object from an array by clicking button?

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular, object

I have typescript file of JSON objects. These JSON objects can be selected as options from a dropdown list. I need to know how to load/instantiate the selected JSON object when the user clicks the button to proceed.

Specifically, I need to understand how to create a function (called 'loadMovies') that will create the JSON object selected from the array.

Movies.ts:

```
export class Movie {
Movies: [];

movies = [
{Genre: "Horror" [...]},
{Genre: "Romance" [...]},
{Genre: "Thiller" [...]},
{Genre: "Adult" [...]},
{Genre: "Action" [...]}
]
}
```

HTML Dropdown List:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select Genre" [(ngModel)]="Movies">
  <mat-option [value]="1">None</mat-option>
  <mat-option [value]="2">Horror</mat-option>
  <mat-option [value]="3">Romance</mat-option>
  <mat-option [value]="4">Thiller</mat-option>
  <mat-option [value]="5">Adult</mat-option>
  <mat-option [value]="6">Action</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let m of movies">{{m.Genre}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

HTML Button:

```
<button mat-button (click)="loadMovies()" >Create</button>
```

loadMovies():

```
?
```

Any help is greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the selected object to the loadMovies function, you can pass the model value directly

```
<button mat-button (click)="loadMovies(Movies)" >Create</button>
```

and in TS

```
loadMovies(Movie :any){
   you should get the value here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan! Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "you should get the value here"?

Comment: you will get the selected value from the dropdown

Comment: For some reason, the 'create'  button doesn't load the json object but I can't figure out why. Is there perhaps a "get JSON" call that I might need to use in the function?

loadMovies(Movie :any){
   > ??? <
}

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-u2fy6c?file=src/app/app.component.html